# Sending Email Twice from PHP

Tags: php, forms, email

I'm doing this simple testing on creating form where I want the form to send email twice:

1. to my email address, to notify me if somebody has reached me
2. to the sender's email address to notify him/her that the contact has been sent to me.

problem is, I could send the first email, but I couldn't send the second one. I thought this should be easy. I may miss a line or two here. Here's the code:

```
<?php
$field_email = $_POST['email'];

$mail_to = 'myemail@mydomain.com';
$subject = 'Message from a site visitor '.$field_name;

$body_message .= 'E-mail: '.$field_email."\n";

$headers = 'From: '.$field_email."\r\n";

$headersTo = 'From: '.$mail_to."\r\n";
$body_messageTo = 'Thank you for your interest';
$subjectTo = 'Thank You from Gaban';

$mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);
$autoreply = mail($field_email, $subjectTo, $body_messageTo, $headersTo);

?>
```

the `$field_email` should take data directly from the "email" form from the HTML code.

Comment: what does your $mail_status and $autoreply contain? do a var_dump on them and check their values

Comment: they should be okay, because the both are just for checking if the form managed to send email to both my email address and the sender's email address. I got the email address from the form, so shouldn't be okay then?

Comment: Go read up on email header injection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless $_POST['email'] contains an invalid email address, I can't see anything wrong with it. I'd say the problem is most likely to be found in the mailserver processing the mailbox where the second email is sent to.